# Docker compose container failure on azure

Tags: python, azure, docker, sqlite, flask

Docker compose failure on azure

I am failing to startup a multi container on azure for a simple test app. In essence I want an app service and a db service that persists so I can access the SQLITE db files and backup/download them, probably using built-in docker tools. I would really appreciate knowing where I am going wrong. I did consult this site first and saw the article on getting the ports right etc, but still no luck.

Here is the relevant info.
TIA.

(1) Trace output from the container log files:

2023-12-03T11:59:23.064Z INFO - Pulling image: ankwilitas/ddm:003

2023-12-03T11:59:24.218Z INFO - 003 Pulling from ankwilitas/ddm

2023-12-03T11:59:24.229Z INFO - Digest: sha256:8e3e612a9d3d51fed11bcd44dedf6c28b0c52137d44e0bc2180451c958c50f9b 2023-12-03T11:59:24.229Z INFO - Status: Image is up to date for ankwilitas/ddm:003

2023-12-03T11:59:24.240Z INFO - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 1 Seconds

2023-12-03T11:59:24.247Z INFO - Starting container for site

2023-12-03T11:59:24.247Z INFO - docker run -d -p 9469:80 --name ddmtestapp_web_0_20931625 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=DDMtestApp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=ddmtestapp.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=6dc581a871e89ead50d499457423099a1bf94aee4ac35dda377966ff7460f7c1 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 ankwilitas/ddm:003

2023-12-03T11:59:24.264Z INFO - Pulling image: docker.io/library/sqlite:latest

2023-12-03T11:59:25.319Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for sqlite, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}

2023-12-03T11:59:25.319Z ERROR - Pulling docker image docker.io/library/sqlite:latest failed:

2023-12-03T11:59:26.333Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for sqlite, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}

2023-12-03T11:59:26.333Z WARN - Image pull failed. Defaulting to local copy if present.

2023-12-03T11:59:26.334Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)

2023-12-03T11:59:26.334Z ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully

2023-12-03T11:59:26.335Z INFO - Container logs from ddmtestapp_web_0_20931625 =

2023-12-03T11:59:26.345Z INFO - Container logs from ddmtestapp_db_0_20931625 =

2023-12-03T11:59:26.437Z INFO - Stopping site ddmtestapp because it failed during startup.

<<< so i have defined a private repo here and provided my login creds for dockerhub... so i don't know why this still fails with sqlite:latest...

(2) Deployment Center Settings:
[![deployment center settings][1]][1]

(3) Docker compose:

````
services:
  web:
    image: ankwilitas/ddm:003
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: "sqlite:latest"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/app/db   # Adjust the volume path based on your app's structure

volumes:
  db_data:```



(4) Dockerfile:
```FROM python:3.7

USER root

#dir for docker:
WORKDIR /ddm

#copy requirements to workdir:
COPY requirements.txt .

#pip install
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install  -v --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

#copy ALL files to workdir
COPY . .```



(5) App.py:

```from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "tbase11"
    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    
    db = sqlite3.connect("db/core/core.db")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT welcome_message FROM service_messages")
    welcome_message = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    db.close()

    return render_template('index.html', welcome_message=welcome_message)```



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT1Rd.png
````

Comment: The "sqlite:latest" does not exist in Docker Hub.

Comment: Thx, i updated the line to pull version 3.35 but still get: DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for sqlite, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"} Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying your Docker configuration, I encountered the same  [error](https://i.imgur.com/SulPjaE.png)  and made changes in the Docker file.

- The simple Flask code below uses SQLite to store and display user names.
- The route (`/`) handles both GET and POST requests.
- If it's a POST request, the user name is retrieved from the form and inserted into the database.
- All users are then retrieved from the database, and the  `index.html`  template is rendered with the user names.Folder [structure](https://i.imgur.com/c2QSmNj.png).
- Code reference from this [DOC](https://data-flair.training/blogs/flask-and-sqlite/).

```py
from  flask  import  Flask,  render_template,  request

import  sqlite3

  

app = Flask(__name__)

  



def  create_table():

conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL)')

conn.commit()

conn.close()

  



def  insert_user(name):

conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)',  (name,))

conn.commit()

conn.close()

  



def  get_users():

conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('SELECT name FROM users')

users = [row[0]  for  row  in  c.fetchall()]

conn.close()

return  users

  



@app.route('/',  methods=['GET',  'POST'])

def  home():

create_table()

  

if  request.method == 'POST':

user_name = request.form['name']

if  user_name:

insert_user(user_name)

  

users = get_users()

return  render_template('index.html',  users=users)

  

if  __name__ == '__main__':

app.run(debug=True)
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Flask App</h1>
    <p>This app uses Python, Flask, and SQLite. Gunicorn is used as the HTTP server to run the Flask application.</p>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Users:</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
            <li>{{ user }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8-slim


WORKDIR /app


COPY . /app


RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt


RUN pip install pipenv


EXPOSE 5000


CMD ["pipenv", "run", "gunicorn", "--bind=0.0.0.0:5000", "--reload", "app:app"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    image: python:3.9
    container_name: python-flask-sqlite
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - FLASK_APP=/src/app.py
      - DATABASE=/src/database.db
    working_dir: /src
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    entrypoint: bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y sqlite3 && pip install --upgrade pip==23.1.2 && pip install -r /src/requirements.txt && gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 4 app:app"
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.3.2
Gunicorn==20.1.0
```

**Local:**

[image]

- Command to build a Docker image:

```bash
docker build --tag python-docker1 .
```

[image]

- Command to run a Docker image:

```bash
docker run -p 5000:5000 python-docker1
```

[image]

- Docker Output:

[image]

- Create a Container registry in azure and [login](https://i.imgur.com/BO4sNfa.png) to Container registry using this command:

```bash
az acr login --name "ContainerRegistryName" --password "Password" --username "ContainerRegistryName"
```

[image]

- The `docker images` command is used to list all the Docker images

[image]

- The `docker tag` command is used to create a tag for a Docker image.

```bash
docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]
```

[image]

- Push a Docker image to a specified container registry.

```bash
docker push IMAGE_NAME
```

[image]

- Select the Repositorie of container [registry](https://i.imgur.com/dxKPXPX.png) in Azure Web [app](https://i.imgur.com/4DINoEV.png) and browse  or refresh the [url](https://i.imgur.com/KLc2Erv.png).

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Sampath - will try later. I'm curious to see if it works when migrated to Azure as a Webapp... e.g. as I understand it, you need to bind to port 8000 on Azure?  Best.

Comment: Yes, it should work, 8000 and 8080 are common HTTP ports for many web. To deploy to the web app follow this reference [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77565744/how-to-deploy-react-native-web-app-with-docker-to-azure-environment/77569333#77569333)

Comment: thanks, once we have tried it we will certainly do that.

Comment: @Sampath - we tried up until the az acr login XXX cmd. however, the CLI returns 'This command requires running the docker daemon, which is not supported in Azure Cloud Shell. You may want to use 'az acr login -n conregank1 --expose-token' to get an access token, ... so we tried the CLI suggestions but still returned error - Error logging in to endpoint, trying next endpoint  error="Get \"https://loginServer/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup loginServer on 168.63.129.16:53: no such host" -  so cannot proceed... please help us, thanks.

Comment: ...so i now see that you have installed azure CLI to your local system, we were using the online / azure CLI. we will try installing the CLI tools to our OSX, thanks for your patience.

Comment: logout from docker in the terminal and use `az login` and then use `az acr login --name "ContainerRegistryName" --password "Password" --username "ContainerRegistryName"`

Comment: it now works successfully, thanks. We need to now test whether we can inspect and download the contents of the persisted volume. i will of course try to learn this now but if you have any advice, we would be grateful, thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately we are unable to download/copy the users.db which is part of the original problem specifiction in this post - we get : Error: No such container:path: 7cffbcf4daa0:/src/users.db        Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Refer to this article about       [where](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) data is [stored](https://medium.com/@tomsowerby/mysql-backup-and-restore-in-docker-fcc07137c757)